# Predicate Logic: Proof of Validity, Satisfiability of Sentences

Tags: predicate-logic

Suppose we are given a sentence (i.e. it has no free variables) of the form: $\forall x$ $(P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$
and asked to determine whether it is a tautology, satisfiable or unsatisfiable.

My questions are:

1) Is the sentence, saying that "for all $x$, $(P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$ is always true?
   To prove that it is not a tautology, would it then be sufficient to state something like "an interpretation that satisfies $P(x)$ would falsify $(P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$. Hence, the sentence is not a tautology." ?

2) Does proving that the sentence is a tautology mean the same thing as proving that the sentence is valid? Would this then mean proving that the sentence is true under all interpretations?

The following is how the terms valid, satisfiability and unsatisfiability are defined.

Let $F$ be a formula of the first order language $L$. $F$ is

1) $valid$ if and only if it is satisfied by every interpretation of $L$.
2) $satisfiable$ if an only if it is satisfied by some interpretation of $L$
3) $unsatisfiable$ if and only if it is not satisfied by any interpretation of $L$

Comment: The method of analytic tableaux might be helpful for the first part of (1).

Answer (score 2):

First you need to check the terminology being used. Some take "tautology" narrowly, to mean -- in effect -- logically valid by the truth-table test (i.e. logically valid solely in virtue of the way the truth-functional connectives appear in the wff). Some  perhaps regrettably employ "tautology" more widely, so that a first-order valid wff counts as a tautology as well.

If you are using tautology in the narrow sense, then quite trivially $\forall x(P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$ is not a tautology in that sense, as its main logical operator is not a truth-function.

It isn't a tautology in the wider sense either, i.e. it is not a first-order valid wff: to show *that* you need to think off an interpretation that makes it false. So pick a domain. And now interpret $P$ and $Q$ such that there are objects in the domain which satisfy $P$ but not $Q$.

Comment: I've edited the question to provide the definitions of "valid", "satisfiable" and "unsatisfiable". Based on the definition, I had assumed that "valid" meant "tautology". Given the definitions, could you clarify whether you think "tautology" is being used to mean the same thing as "valid"?

Comment: I was wondering, how prevalent in modern *predicate logic* texts is the treatment of tautology and validity as synonyms? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If, after Peter's answer, you are still using *tautology* in *predicate logic* as synonym of *valid* (i.e. *true* in all interpretations), then your definitions are the right ones.

Regarding :

> 2) Does proving that the sentence is a tautology mean the same thing as proving that the sentence is valid? Would this then mean proving that the sentence is true under all interpretations?

Now the answer is : **YES**. According to the above stipulation, they means the same thing.

But now :

> 1) Is the sentence, saying that "for all x, (P(x)→Q(x))" is always true? To prove that it is not a tautology, would it then be sufficient to state something like "an interpretation that satisfies P(x) would falsify (P(x)→Q(x)). Hence, the sentence is not a tautology" ?

makes little sense.

To prove that $∀x (P(x)→Q(x))$ is **not** always true (i.e. not *valid*) we have to find an interpretation which flasify "for all x, (P(x)→Q(x))".

Again, by Peter's answer, this must be an interpretation with *domain* $\mathcal U$ such that we have at least one object $a \in \mathcal U$ for which $P$ holds of it and $Q$ does not.

Consider an interpretation with the set $\mathbb N$ of *natural numbers* as domain and consider the two "predicates" $(x > 0)$ and $(x < 0)$ as interpretation of $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ respectively.

We have that $1 > 0$ is *true* while $1 < 0$ is *false*.  Thus :

> $(1 > 0) \rightarrow (1 < 0)$ is *false* [truth-table for $\rightarrow$].

So, we have found a number $n$ such that :

$(n > 0) \rightarrow (n < 0)$ is *false* in $\mathbb N$

and we can conclude with :

> $\forall x[(x > 0) \rightarrow (x < 0)]$ is *false* in $\mathbb N$.

*Conclusion*

We have found an interpretation of $∀x (P(x)→Q(x))$ which falsify it; thus, the formula is not *valid*.